# How do I run 2 multiple Kafka Mirror Maker instances on same server or cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, production-environment

How do I run 2 multiple Kafka Mirror Maker instances on same server or cluster?

- We have a requirement where the servers are in different data centres and looking to use Kafka as a message broker.
- And Kafka Mirror Maker as the sync.
- But I have to run multiple mirror maker instances on the same server.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer to my own question.

Mirror Maker is just a process. If we want to run multiple mirror makers we can just run the start command twice.